# How to find data from array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have collection like this:

```
{
    "name":"silver",
    mywants:[
    {"_id":objid(545454ddfdf5),mark:{"english":100,"math":100,"science":100}},
    {"_id":objid(5878784dfd5d),mark:{"english":100,"math":100,"science":100}},
    {"_id":objid(5454dfd44545),mark:{"english":100,"math":100,"science":100}},
    {"_id":objid(541dfee88245),mark:{"english":100,"math":100,"science":100}},
    ]
}
```

I want to find that given objid is exist in mywants array or not. Then if exist that objid  i want that  exist object id document to my callback function so i have tried like this

```
collection.find("{"name":"silver"},{"mywants._id":objid}).toArray(function(err,res)
{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
})

But, I got output like 

[{"Mywant":[{"_id":"5128b9bc046802720b000003"},
    {"_id":"5128c190046802720b000004"},
    {"_id":"5128c359175e1aa80b000001"}],"_id":"5128b71455e4e0540b000002"}
]
```

But i want like this

```
{"_id":objid(545454ddfdf5),mark:{"english":100,"math":100,"science":100}}`,
```

How to find?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call

```
collection.find({"name":"silver", "mywants._id":objid}).toArray(…)
```

instead of

```
collection.find({"name":"silver"},{"mywants._id":objid}).toArray(…)
```

. The former one represents a query with two expressions ("name":"silver" AND "mywants._id":objid) while the latter one is one expression ("name":"silver") and one projection ("mywants._id":objid) [controls the fields to return]. More info at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/.

Comment: if i use like above i got this error                       SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: I edited my answer and omitted the inner braces, please check if it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in your code, it is not ver clear what youwant. Based on your sample with typo and output you want (again with typo) I assume this is what you meant:

-You are doing a find on name:"silver" and want back mywants._id field (has typo) with that syntax.

Instead I assume you meant to find:

name:"silver" AND "mywants._id" : someSpecificId

and output corresponding mywants entry:

```
db.collection.find({"name":"silver","mywants._id":objid}, {"mywants.$":1, _id:0}).pretty()
```